# Insert into mysql database not committing changes (python)

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am trying to run the following code which executes with no issues. The sql that is produced is, "INSERT INTO account_login (groupone_account_id, login_date) VALUES ('100', '10:10:00') which has no syntax errors and executed successfully. But when I check the table, the id has not been inserted. I can complete select queries successfully.

The reason why I created database_connection is because it is an external connection and I wanted to isolate it to be able to test the databse connection easier.

```
def create_groupone_account_login(groupone_account_id):
    groupone_account_login_created = False
    cursor = database_connection("cursor")
    time = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'
    sql_create_account_login = "INSERT INTO account_login (groupone_account_id, login_date) VALUES ('%s', '%s')" % (
            groupone_account_id, time)
    cursor.execute(sql_create_account_login)
    connection = database_connection("connection")
    connection.commit()
    cursor.close()
    groupone_account_login_created = True
    return groupone_account_login_created
```

```
def database_connection(variable):
    resp_dict = json.loads(get_secret())
    endpoint = resp_dict.get('host')
    username = resp_dict.get('username')
    password = resp_dict.get('password')
    database_name = resp_dict.get('dbname')
    port = resp_dict.get('port')
    connection = pymysql.connect(host=endpoint, user=username, passwd=password, db=database_name, port=port)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    if variable == "connection":
        return connection
    else:
        return cursor
```

Comment: use `cursor.rowcount` in order to see how many records were inserted.

Comment: @balderman I get rowcount as 1 but again do not see the insert in the table

Comment: what you are doing with `database_connection` does not feel right. Can you try and use the same conn/cursor - without calling it twice.

Comment: as you have suggested, it has worked when I internalised everything into the function. I am guessing becauses database_connection("connection") calls the function again and it is somehow not the same 'connection' as cursor?

Comment: !resolved ; changed the function database_connection to a class GetDatabaseConnection where I was able to directly call the variables cursor and connection.